# How to delete a row from an Existing Excel Sheet using JXL

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I am not able to delete row of an existing excel sheet using JXL.
Are there any other way to delete a row from and existing workbook?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = endLine -1 ; i >= startLine -1 ; i--) { wSheet.removeRow(i);}
```

Remember that the JXL will elevate all the following lines when this line is deleted, so try to delete lines backwards in order to avoid the alternative deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new   File("output.xls"));
   WritableSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("some sheet");

   //delete row 10

   sheet.removeRow(10);
```

Comment: i have tried the same. but only alternate rows are getting deleted.

Comment: what do you mean by alternate row?

Comment: For some strange reason, I have the exactly same code and Is messing up the excel file. Literally this lines of code are converting my excel file into a 0KB files :-(. Any advice?

Comment: Debug: Dump sheet to make sure it references the correct sheet, check to make sure `sheet.removeRow(N)` is set to remove the right row. Make sure removeRow is not called in a loop removing each indexed row.